# Trouble with Binding image to List

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

I need Binding `List` with `Image` to `ListView` but it doesnt work correctly

My class with `List`

```
    public Image FrameImage { get; set; } = new Image();

    public string Path { get; set; }

    private static List<FramesViewModel> framesCollection = new List<FramesViewModel>
    {
        new FramesViewModel() { FrameImage = {Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:/Frames/Frame1.png"))}, Path = @"Frames\Frame1.png"},
    };
    public static List<FramesViewModel> FramesCollection => framesCollection;
```

And my XAML

```
  <ListView 
        ItemsSource="{Binding FramesCollection}"
        DataContext="{StaticResource FramesViewModel}">
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border    
            Width="250"
            Height="150">
                <Border.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" 
                            ImageSource="{Binding FrameImage}"/>
                </Border.Background>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Besides the missing `<ListView.ItemTemplate>` tag, the type of the `FrameImage` property must not be `Image`, but `ImageSource` (or a derived type) instead. You would then write `new FramesViewModel { FrameImage = new BitmapImage(...) }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XAMl you're missining the `ListView.ItemTemplate` wrapping `DataTemplate`

My Example

```
class FramesViewModel
{
    public BitmapImage FrameImage { get; set; } = new BitmapImage();


    private static List<FramesViewModel> framesCollection = new List<FramesViewModel>
{
    new FramesViewModel() { FrameImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://www.citgroup.in/images/icon/wcf.png"))},

};
    public static List<FramesViewModel> FramesCollection => framesCollection;

}
```

and

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:FramesViewModel x:Key="FramesVM" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListView 
    ItemsSource="{Binding FramesCollection}"
    DataContext="{StaticResource FramesVM}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border    
        Width="250"
        Height="150">
                <Border.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" 
                        ImageSource="{Binding FrameImage}"/>
                </Border.Background>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks! i missed it